# IN mvvm how notify store data in datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

here i am working on mvvm .i want to notify uodate in datgrid if any change in textbox occur.what is the code for that?

```
 public void Save()
        {if (IsNew)
                _accountCategoryDataSource.Add(_accountCategory);
```

the above code for add data in database

and below code for loading data in datagrid  for viewing

```
private void LoadAllAccounts()
        {
            _allAccounts =
                (from account in _accountDataSource.GetAll() as List<Account>
                 select new AccountViewModel(account, _accountDataSource)).ToList();
            Accounts = new ObservableCollection<AccountViewModel>(_allAccounts);

            if (Accounts.Count > 0)
                SelectedAccount = Accounts[0];
        }`
```

BUT i can not have code for showing update in datagrid how it is done?

Comment: how are grid/accounts and textbox related as a data, what's in textbox

Comment: @NSGaga :Here grid display account information and using text-box we can   give value such as account_name ,account_owner etc for storing/update it in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your datagrids ItemsSource property bound to that collection of Accounts?  If so, do your Account class and AccountViewModel class implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  If it does not, you must implement that interface to get changes propagated to the UI.

Take a look here for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

Comment: using  this link  i can update text-box value in data grid.but how i can update value in data base .

Comment: It depends on what you are using to talk to the database.  If you are using Entity Framework, call SaveChanges() on the DbContext that contains the object that you have updated.  The appropriate update statement will be sent to the database.  What ORM or storage solution are you using?